# Word meaning to 'beat to the punch' or to act to mitigate they're anticipated is going to happen

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word that's escaping me at the moment.

For example, if a politician has sent some risque texts to his intern, and he knows that she's going to take them to the media, he might call a media conference and announce that he's been acting inappropriately and resign, *before* she does, as to mitigate the fallout.

Comment: One can say he **staved off** or **averted** the anticipated bad result, or that he **obviated** it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preemptive** sounds like the word you might be thinking of:

- After the politician's indiscretion, he resigned *preemptively.*
- To *preempt* a media circus, the politician resigned before the intern went public.

I think the adversarial overtones fit the example you describe well. Some illustrative examples from Google Books:

> For instance, reflecting on the creation and introduction of the Stuxnet virus as a new type of preemptive cyber-weapon will reveal practical implications of the integration of preemptive cyber weapons into operational planning.

[The Evolution of Preemptive Strikes in Israeli Operational Planning and Future Implications for the Cyber Domain](https://books.google.com/books?id=3GqxBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&dq=preemptive&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCGoVChMIsM3vwb7cxgIVRlyICh0YHwws#v=onepage&q=preemptive&f=false)

> Interestingly Jacob criticized his sons for "stirring up trouble," fearing perhaps that other clans would now feel it necessary to take preemptive action against his aggressive clan.

[Preemption: A Knife That Cuts Both Ways](https://books.google.com/books?id=-3ZHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&dq=preemptive&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBTgUahUKEwi4joaNv9zGAhVRMYgKHdAcC1g#v=onepage&q=preemptive&f=false)

Comment: I see you answered about 10 seconds before I did. You want me to take mine down?

Comment: I'm inclined to say no. I think we took different enough approaches: You provided definitions whereas I provided example sentences, and you included an alternative but I did not. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for **[pre-empt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pre-empt?q=preempt)**?

> 1. Take action in order to prevent (an anticipated event) happening; forestall:
> 2. Act in advance of (someone) in order to prevent them doing something:

**[Forestall](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/forestall)** could also be used

> **forestall something/somebody** (formal) to prevent something from happening or somebody from doing something by doing something first